# LINQ ordering by a child value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an EF model that looks like:

```
public class MetaData
{
    public ICollection<MetaDataDictionary> MetaDataDictionary { get; set; }
}

public partial class MetaDataDictionary
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public List<MetaData> MetaDataList { get; set; }
```

...so I could have an instance like:

```
MetaDataList 
  MetaData1
    MetaDataDictionary          
      { key = "aaa", value = "4" }
      { key = "bbb", value = "5" }     
      { key = "ccc", value = "6" }     
  MetaData2
    MetaDataDictionary 
      { key = "aaa", value = "1" }
      { key = "bbb", value = "2" }     
      { key = "ccc", value = "3" }
```

The goal is to sort MetaDataList based on a value of a specific key (for example key "aaa") of the MetaDataDictionary, output should be:

```
MetaDataList 
  MetaData1
    MetaDataDictionary          
      { key = "aaa", value = "1" }
      { key = "bbb", value = "2" }     
      { key = "ccc", value = "3" }     
  MetaData2
    MetaDataDictionary 
      { key = "aaa", value = "4" }
      { key = "bbb", value = "5" }     
      { key = "ccc", value = "6" }
```

As you see, it is now sorted on values of key "bbb".

I tried:

```
var sorted = metaDataList.OrderBy(md => md.MetaDataDictionary.Select(mdd => mdd.Key == "aaa").Single()).ToList();
```

...but it complains about 'DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable'.

Any pointers how I can make this work?

Thanks!

EDIT: just tried this:

```
var sorted = metaDataList.OrderBy(md => md.MetaDataDictionary.Where(mdd => mdd.Key == "aaa").Select(mdd => mdd.Value).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Seems to work, but if someone has a better solution, feel free to share :)

Comment: Yours is already the shortest form. You *could* try `.OrderBy(md => md.MetaDataDictionary.FirstOrDefault(mdd => mdd.Key == "aaa").Value)` (SQL queries don't throw `NullReferenceException` :-) ) but I'm not sure it is "compatible" with EF

Comment: My best guess: `var sorted = metaDataList.Select(md=>md.MetaDataDictionary.OrderBy(mdd=>mdd.Key));`

Comment: On the second look, your data are not sorted by specific key. They are sorted by Value. So, second guess is: `var qry = MetaDataList.SelectMany(x=>x.MetaDataDictionary.Select(y=>y)).OrderBy(a=>a.Value);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
metaDataList.OrderBy(md => md.MetaDataDictionary.First(mdd => mdd.Key == "aaa").Value)
            .ToList();
```

I haven't tested it yet but believe it should work.